# Convertir caracteres ASCII a string

Tags: android-studio, ascii

tengo una tarea muy importante y a la vez estresante, estoy trabajando con un grupo de ingenieros electrónicos y nuestro sistema trata de medir parámetros del agua de unos estanques, funciona mediante radio frecuencia y wifi, para hacer mas corto el tema yo recibo una larga cadena de caracteres ASCII por medio de wifi, osea los obtengo por medio de Socket, InputStream, etc.

un ejemplo de la cadena que recibo
"#4$2: /8"b: !i$b:"
por cada ":" es un estanque que debo de separar, es decir, en mi aplicación yo debo de decodificar toda esa cadena de caracteres para y de alguna forma ingresar puntos(.) y comas(,) para tener una vista de los parámetros decodificados, ejemplo

"35.52,38.50" = "#4$2" debo de agregar un punto entre cada 2 caracteres, es decir #.4,$.2

alguna manera de decodificar toda esa cadena y poner puntos y comas? algún hilo para poder guiarme por favor, les dejo una imagen de la vista que debo de tener mas o menos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, deberías añadir el código de lo que tienes hecho o un ejemplo más claro de los datos que tienes y cómo quieres procesarlos. Ni siquiera sabemos si estás usando Java, Kotlin u otro lenguaje compatible para crear tu aplicación. Hablas de transformar carateres ASCII a String, pero no comentas si es que recibes un array de `char` o ya tienes un String con esos valores

Comment: Hola Julian, llevas algo de tiempo en el sitio y hasta el día de hoy no has revisado [ask] , ni realizado el [tour], del sitio, te sugerimos revises estos documentos y agregues más información a tu pregunta, en este caso como menciona Pablo, tu código , define que lenguaje estas usando, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

La decodificación de la cadena de texto es sencilla con aplicar esta función sería suficiente.

```
private String convertTextToAscii(String text){
    String resultText = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length() ; i++){
        int ascii = (int) text.charAt(i);
        resultText += ascii;
    }
    return resultText;
}

//Para llamarla
convertTextToAscii("#4$2")
```

Para añadir las comas y puntos lo dejo para ti creo que es un proceso bastante trivial si sabes que los números serán siempre ##.##, ##.##. Con esto creo que puedes empezar, esto tampoco es para una programación a la carta :)

Comment: No funciona?? Me podéis dar feedback?